# Is it possible to specify a linker flag so a static library is not linked?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, linker

Is it possible to specify a linker flag in OTHER_LDFLAGS so a static library is not linked?

Comment: If you remove it from the Link Binary with Libraries phase, it won't be linked.

Comment: Understood, I want it in the Link Binary with Library phase but selectively disable that in OTHER_LDFLAGS based on the configuration.  Possible?

Comment: Don't think that's possible, but the reverse certainly is (add a `-l` flag to `OTHER_LDFLAGS` to link a particular library on a per-configuration basis).